# mkfifo() creating file goes wrong

Tags: c, windows, pipe, named-pipes, fifo

I'm learning about named pipes. When I do `mkfifo()` nothing happens, I don't get a extra file in my folder where I can write to or read from. Any suggestions?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    mkfifo("C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\codes", 0666);
}
```

Comment: mkfifo returns a status. You can use perror() to see what the actual error was.  So do `int s = mkfifo(...); if(s<0){ perror("mkfifo error:");}`

Comment: I don't think Windows supports named pipes.

Comment: @Shawn: In fact Windows does (and I have used them), but they can't appear on an NTFS filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a named pipe on any of the default Windows filesystems; nor would be 0666 be the right permissions if you wanted to. Portable calls to this class functions use symbolic constants that expend do different values on different operation systems, but I digress.

If you need a named pipe on Windows, you would call [CreateNamedPipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea). This actually results in a path that you could in theory hand to another program. However pipes on Windows are a little bit special and should not be handed to programs expecting a file. Thus the obvious way is the right way, tell the program to open the named pipe and give it the name to pass to CreateNamedPipe itself. If the program is not expecting a named pipe, it would most likely not work even if you passed it one as an open file handle.